# Read columns from csv file and put them into a new csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the current code using pandas:

```
file1_csv = 'fileX.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file1_csv, header=None, usecols=[0,43])
print (data)
```

The result is this:

```
          0          43
0  57669557  2020-02-15
1  57779240  2017-02-15
2  96951148  2018-07-24
```

What I need is to put this result into a new csv file and have something like this:

```
col1, col2
57669557,2020-02-15
57779240,2017-02-15
96951148,2018-07-24
```

My code is like this:

```
final = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1','col2'])
final.to_csv('finalFile.csv', index=False)
```

But the output is wrong and generates the next:

```
col1,col2
,
,
,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor with an already indexed structure (like a another `DataFrame`). The `columns` argument, *selects* values from the existing index, it does not overwrite the index names.

We need to do something like:

```
final = pd.DataFrame(data)
final.columns = ['col1', 'col2']  # Overwrite Column Names
final.to_csv('finalFile.csv', index=False)
```

Or get a non-indexed structure like an `array` ([`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html)):

```
# Break existing index alignment
final = pd.DataFrame(data.to_numpy(), columns=['col1','col2'])
final.to_csv('finalFile.csv', index=False)
```

*Or any of the many other ways to [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) or overwrite ([`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html)) the existing columns

These approaches produce the expected `finalFile.csv`:

```
col1,col2
57669557,2020-02-15
57779240,2017-02-15
96951148,2018-07-24
```

---

Take a look at this toy example showing `columns` selecting values from the existing DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    0: [57669557, 57779240, 96951148],
    43: ['2020-02-15', '2017-02-15', '2018-07-24']
})
print(data)
final = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[43])
print(final)
```

Program output:

```
# data
         0           43
0  57669557  2020-02-15
1  57779240  2017-02-15
2  96951148  2018-07-24

# final (Only column 43 was selected)
           43
0  2020-02-15
1  2017-02-15
2  2018-07-24
```